# Deadlock Catch into a Function Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, function

I am currently using a deadlock catch on certain gridview databinds in vb.net.

I was wondering if there was a way I could put the Deadlock Catch's code into a function in a separate Form so I could perform the catch in my vb so I could do it with less visible code:

this is the code for my deadlock catch:

```
            Dim retryCount As Integer = 0
            Try
retry:
                GridView1.DataBind()
            Catch ex As SqlException
                If ex.Number = 1205 Then
                    If retryCount < 3 Then
                        GoTo retry
                    Else
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                    End If
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                End If
            End Try
```

Would there be a way I could put this code into a function so I could call it in a lot less code?

Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thank you In advance.

Comment: You shouldn't use shouldn't be using GoTO in this manner. What you should do is return true/false from your method and then have that method called from another method which has a loop-structure that retries as long as the result is false or hits your 'breakout' counter.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen I will try that, Appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use GoTo, isn't a good practice and depending on your code complexity it will turn the whole thing in a monster. I recommend you to code this way:

```
Private Function SourceDataBind(ByVal grdView As DataGridView) As Boolean
  Try
    grdView.DataBind()
  Catch ex as SqlException
    If ex.Number = 1205 Then
      Return False
    End If
  End Try

  Return True
End Function

Private Sub DoBindings()
  Dim retryCount As Integer = 0

  Do While retryCount < 3
    If SourceDataBind(GridView1) Then Exit Do
    retryCount += 1
  Loop

End Sub
```

Hope this helps. Best Regards.

Comment: this looks good, is there a way I could pass the ID of the gridview to the function as oppose to calling the individual gridview ID in the actual function (because there will be cases when I need different Gridviews databindind)